# Is there a way to create a cycle to run specified amount of projects in day?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cycle

I have project which runs a function every day to update data about several projects. But this data fetching is heavy and takes a lot of time. So I would like to distribute the number of projects fetched on every day basis.

1. If data fetching for Proj-1, Proj-2 runs on monday, then data fetching would again run for this projects on thursday.
2. Similarly, data fetching for Proj-3, Proj-4 runs on tuesday, then data fetching would again run for this projects on friday.

I want to create this cycle, is there anyway or any ideas to achieve this. Any help from your side would be much appreciated.

P.S - I am using Node JS and projects are saved using MongoDB

Comment: What do you use currently to trigger the function?

Comment: I am using Nest JS so I am using the built-in Cron from @nestjs/schedule.

Comment: I assumed so. Can you not then adjust your schedule to meet these needs? Example: (00**TUE) would run every Tuesday

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of code that shows your cron schedule currently?